# If $f$ is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ and $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\ dx=2$, find $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^xtf(t)\ dt}{x}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

If $f$ is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ and $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\ dx=2$, find $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^xtf(t)\ dt}{x}$.

I thought about using L'Hospital's rule so that the  $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^xtf(t)\ dt}{x}$ becomes $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}xf(x)$. But then I am lost... Could anyone share any hint please?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t)dt$. Then $\int_0^{x} tf(t)dt=tF(t)|_0^{x}-\int_0^{x}F(t)dt=xF(x)-\int_0^{x}F(t)dt$. When divided by $x$ the first term tends to $F(\infty)=2$. Use the fact that $F(\infty)=2$ to show that $\frac 1x \int_0^{x} F(t)dt \to 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G(x)=\int\limits_x^\infty f(t)\,dt.$ Then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}G(x)=0$ and
$${1\over x}\int\limits_0^xtf(t)\,dt={1\over x}\int\limits_0^x\int\limits_0^tf(t)\,ds \,dt =\int\limits_0^x\int\limits_s^xf(t)\,dt={1\over x}\int\limits_0^x[G(s)-G(x)]\,ds\\ ={1\over x}\int\limits_0^xG(s)\,ds -G(x) \underset{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0
$$

**Remark** Your method works fine provided the function $f(x)$ is positive and decreasing. In that case
$$\int\limits_{x/2}^xf(t)\,dt \ge {x\over 2}f(x)\ge 0$$
Hence $xf(x)\to 0$ when $x\to \infty$ and L'Hospital rule is effective.